# Snowflake SQL: How to loop through array with JSON objects, to find item that meets condition

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

Breaking my head on this. In Snowflake my field `city_info` looks like (for 3 sample records)

```
[{"name": "age", "content": 35}, {"name": "city", "content": "Chicago"}]
[{"name": "age", "content": 20}, {"name": "city", "content": "Boston"}]
[{"name": "city", "content": "New York"}, {"name": "age", "content": 42}]
```

I try to extract a column `city` from this

```
Chicago
Boston
New York
```

I tried to flatten this

```
select *
from lateral flatten(input =>
  select city_info::VARIANT as event
  from data
)
```

And from there I can derive the value, but this only allows me to do this for 1 row (so I have to add `limit 1` which doesn't makes sense, as I need this for all my rows).

If I try to do it for the 3 rows it tells me `subquery returns more than one row.`

Any help is appreciated! Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write it as:

```
SELECT value:content::string AS city_name
FROM tab,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => tab.city_info)
WHERE value:name::string = 'city'
```